# Error while rails new <app name> and installing openssl gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rubygems

I am trying to execute `rails new <app name>` but it won't let me do that it says:
`incompatible library version - /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.bundle (LoadError)`

Here is the traceback:

```
    40: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    39: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    38: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    37: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    36: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    35: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    34: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    33: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    32: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    31: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    30: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    29: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
    28: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    27: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    26: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
    25: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
    24: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
    23: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
    22: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    21: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    20: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:382:in `create_master_key'
    19: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:165:in `build'
    18: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:165:in `public_send'
    17: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:184:in `master_key'
    16: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    15: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    14: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/generators/rails/master_key/master_key_generator.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    12: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    11: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/generators/rails/encryption_key_file/encryption_key_file_generator.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     9: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     8: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     6: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     5: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     3: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     2: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
```

and when I try to reinstall the openssl gem it says:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": incompatible library version - /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": incompatible library version - /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    incompatible library version - /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Update: When I try to install rbenv 2.7.1 or rbenv 2.7.4 it says:

```
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1
  --with-openssl-dir=/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/openssl
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  CFLAGS= -DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libressl/lib
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libressl/include
```

These are the lines from tail of the log:

`/var/folders/9r/wlddqf8x7g7351d29pwq203h0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210806201413.89891.log`
I have tried using openssl@1.0 with many difficulties I don't know what to do after this to install this. I have tried RUBY_CONFIG_OPTS and CONFIG_OPTS approach too but all in vain.

Comment: rails version ?

Comment: @JuxSalley Rails 6.1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

run `gem install railties` and if the problem persist install OpenSSL using brew

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    OpenSSl is not available. Install OpenSSL and rebuild Ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

Comment: Brew installation of openssl@1.1 successfully completes then too this error

Comment: Update: gem install succeeded with gem pristine openssl --version 2.2.0

Comment: try reinstalling ruby using rbenv

Comment: tried that it gives error, please see update in the question

Comment: rbenv install 2.7.2

Comment: same error The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2
  --with-openssl-dir=/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/openssl
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  CFLAGS= -DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include